# iterate through ids and use in query postgres function

Tags: postgresql, function, loops

#### For context

I want to create a function in postgres that populates a junction table `pokemon_trainers` which has following columns

- `id`
- `trainer_id`
- `pokemon_id`

`trainer_id` is a reference to a row in the table `trainers`

and `pokemon_id` is a reference to a row in the table
`pokemons`

Each trainer should have 6 pokemon. So if there is 10000 trainers, there should be 60000 rows in the `pokemon_trainers` table.
I would like to solve this in postgres, not being dependent on the application to handle the logic.

#### Actual problem

I assume it should iterate through each `trainer` row and perform 6 inserts for each `trainer`.

Èach insert tries to select a random `pokemons.id` to use, which seemingly works fine. However I have some trouble with defining the `trainer.id` and use it inside of the `INSERT` query inside of the nested loop.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION populate_trainer_pokemons() 
  RETURNS VOID 
AS
$$
DECLARE 
   trainer_pokemon trainer_pokemons%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR trainer_pokemon in SELECT id FROM trainer_pokemons LOOP
  FOR i IN 0..6 LOOP
        INSERT INTO trainer_pokemons(trainer_pokemon.id, pokemon_id)
VALUES(trainer_id, (SELECT
   FLOOR(RANDOM() *
   (
      (SELECT
             min(id)  
          FROM
             pokemons) -
      ((SELECT
            max(id)  
         FROM
            pokemons) + 1
   )) +1
) + 
(SELECT
   max(id)  
FROM
   pokemons)));
   END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```sql
SELECT populate_trainer_pokemons();
```

produces following error:

> ERROR:  column "trainer_pokemon" of relation "trainer_pokemons" does not exist
> LINE 1: INSERT INTO trainer_pokemons(trainer_pokemon.id, pokemon_id)

I have tried to fiddle around with the variable names and the declared type, and I cannot seem to find any concrete examples that tries to do something similar.

How should I make the function work?

Comment: What is a "middletable"?

Comment: I think you mixed up value and column name: `INSERT INTO trainer_pokemons(trainer_id, pokemon_id)
VALUES(trainer_pokemon.id, (…))`

Comment: @Bergi might be wrong terminology, a table used to connect a many to many relationship. That is not the solution apparently

Comment: Ah, ok, in that case the table should not have an `id` column though - unless a trainer can train the same pokemon multiple times? Iirc *junction table* is the right term. Edit: [across many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), apparently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a function or expensive loops. This can be done with a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO trainer_pokemons(trainer_id, pokemon_id)
select tr.id, x.id
from trainers tr
  cross join lateral (
    select id
    from pokemons
    order by random() 
    limit 6
  ) x
```

Comment: That certainly looks interesting! I just tried to run it, it inserted 14839 rows, when there exists 4946 trainers. It was tested with 3 pokemons in the pokemon table. The trainer_pokemons table has a seperate id column. So I don't think it is due to unique values. What do you think?